# Formula for the transition from tensors to vectors in matrix calculus

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Given quadratic norm:

$f=\boldsymbol{g}^T\boldsymbol{p}=\boldsymbol{g}^TQ\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$

where $\boldsymbol{g}=\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ -9.81 \end{array} \right]$

$Q=R_z(\psi)R_y(\xi)R_x(\phi)$ - rotation matrix;    $\boldsymbol{\theta}=\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \phi \\ \xi \\ \psi \end{array} \right]$

I need to get $\frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, i.e. a vector $df=\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{\phi}} \\ \frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{\xi}} \\ \frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{\psi}} \end{array} \right]$

**My developments:**

With the help of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251079/derivative-matrix-by-vector-in-mathematica

I can get the derivative of the matrix $Q$ with respect to the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and get the tensor $T_{3 \times 9}$ as a result.

Then I use a formula

$\frac{dQ}{d\phi}=T_{3 \times 9}(I_{3 \times 3}\otimes\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right])$

*where $I_{3 \times 3}$ - identity matrix, $\otimes$ - Kronecker product;*

to extract from the tensor the derivative of the rotation matrix $Q$ by angle $\phi$, but there is only $\frac{dQ}{d\phi}$.

*What formula to use to get the whole vector $\frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$* ?

Code for the procedure in Mathematica:

```
Rx = RotationMatrix[\[Phi][t], {1, 0, 0}]; Ry = 
 RotationMatrix[\[Xi][t], {0, 1, 0}]; Rz = 
 RotationMatrix[\[Psi][t], {0, 0, 1}];

Q = Rz.Ry.Rx;

p = Q.{{0}, {0}, {1}};

g = {{0}, {0}, {-9.81}};

T = Flatten /@ D[Q, {{\[Phi][t], \[Xi][t], \[Psi][t]}}];

T.Transpose[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], {1, 0, 0}]] // 
  MatrixForm;
```

**EDIT:**

I found one method that only uses $\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, and the result is the same as direct differentiation $\frac{dQ^T}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$. The disadvantage of this method is the need to glue the matrix again. Maybe I can get around this with some kind of unified tensor operation ? To immediately receive the entire matrix, without additional gluing.

```
Rx = RotationMatrix[\[Phi][t], {1, 0, 0}];

Ry = RotationMatrix[\[Xi][t], {0, 1, 0}];

Rz = RotationMatrix[\[Psi][t], {0, 0, 1}];

Q = Rz.Ry.Rx;

v = {\[Phi][t], \[Xi][t], \[Psi][t]};

T1 = Flatten /@ D[Q, {v}];

T2 = Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}];

P1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

A1 = T1.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

A2 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};

A3 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

Transpose[P1.ArrayFlatten[{{A1}, {A2}, {A3}}]] == 
   Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}] // MatrixForm;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Rodrigues rotation formula to represent rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\mathbf{R}(\alpha) = \mathbf{I} + \sin{\alpha}\mathbf{K} + (1-\cos{\alpha})\mathbf{K}^2$$

where matrix $\mathbf{K}$ encodes vector product with axis of rotation. For given vector $\mathbf{k}$ and any vector $\mathbf{x}$:

$$\mathbf{K} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{k}\times \mathbf{x}$$

Then it is easy to compute derivative of $\mathbf{R}(\alpha)$ against $\alpha$
$$\frac{d}{d \alpha} \mathbf{R}(\alpha) = \cos\alpha\mathbf{K} + \sin\alpha\mathbf{K}^2 = \mathbf{K}\mathbf{R}(\alpha) $$
The last transition is tricky but useful. You can derive it by computing derivative of composition of rotations:
$$\frac{d}{d \alpha} \mathbf{R}(\alpha) = \left.\frac{d}{d \beta}\mathbf{R}(\alpha+\beta) \right|_{\beta=0} = \left.\frac{d}{d \beta} \mathbf{R}(\beta)\mathbf{R}(\alpha) \right|_{\beta=0} = (\cos\beta\mathbf{K} + \sin\beta\mathbf{K}^2)\mathbf{R}(\alpha) = \mathbf{K}\mathbf{R}(\alpha)$$
The solution to your problem becomes then:
$$\frac{d}{d \phi} \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{p} = \frac{d}{d \phi} \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{R}_x(\psi)\mathbf{p}_0 = \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{K}_z\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{R}_x(\psi)\mathbf{p}_0$$
Analogously for other axes
$$\frac{d}{d \varepsilon} \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{K}_y\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{R}_x(\psi)\mathbf{p}_0$$
$$\frac{d}{d \psi} \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{g}^T\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{K}_x\mathbf{R}_x(\psi)\mathbf{p}_0$$
The three formulas produce scalars, which can be packed in vector $\mathbf{\theta}$. You can express the packing step as a matrix operation as well. If we now interpret your  matrix $T$ as a concatenation of matrix derivatives:
$$\mathbf{T}_{9\times 3} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{K}_z\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{R}_x(\psi) \\
\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{K}_y\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{R}_x(\psi) \\
\mathbf{R}_z(\phi)\mathbf{R}_y(\varepsilon)\mathbf{K}_x\mathbf{R}_x(\psi)
\end{array}\right]$$
If your software produces matrix $\tilde{T}$ with differently ordered columns and rows, you can shuffle them by applying relevant permutation matrices $\mathbf{P}_{9\times 9}$ and $\mathbf{P}_{3\times 3}$:
$$\mathbf{T}_{9\times 3} = \mathbf{P}_{9\times 9} \tilde{\mathbf{T}}_{9\times 3} \mathbf{P}_{3\times 3}$$
The packing step can now be expressed as a matrix operation.
$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{\theta}} f = (\mathbf{g}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_{3\times 3})\mathbf{T}\mathbf{p}_0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm looking for a formula that allows you to get the entire vector as a whole, without packaging individual components. For example, let's take square norm $x^TAx$, her derivative by x, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}x^TAx=x^T(A+A^T)$. That is, I need an expression in the same vector-matrix form.

Comment: I see. The packing step can be expressed as a matrix operation as well, as long ass we have the matrix $T$, which itself is concatenation of matrix derivatives. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Now I will try this method. First, please tell me the dimensions I need $I$ and $P$

Comment: See update. I've added subscripts where relevant.

Comment: I tested this method in mathematica - it works. Thank you very much for your clear and qualified help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Please, see my edit

Comment: Which matrix are you talking about? $T$? If you are happy to use tensor notation a lot of things get easier. Im not familiar with Mathematica. Some objects that appear in your algorithm have more than two dimensions. Especially in the extended problem in other question. Since $Q$ is a 3x3 matrix, $\frac{dQ}{d\theta}$ has 27 components. The gluing is effectively a way to represent the 3d object as 2d matrix.

Comment: https://ibb.co/9YN4Vbf there is my comments with suitable representation