# One more question about matrix calculus: this time about skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, tensor-products, kronecker-product

[Formula for the transition from tensors to vectors in matrix calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201386/formula-for-the-transition-from-tensors-to-vectors-in-matrix-calculus)

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251079/derivative-matrix-by-vector-in-mathematica

*Given:*

1. $Q=R_z(\psi)R_y(\xi)R_x(\phi)$ - rotation matrix
2. $\boldsymbol{\theta}=\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \phi \\ \xi \\ \psi 
       \end{array} \right]$ - vector of angles
3. $p=Q\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right]$ -
   vector
4. $[p]_×=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -p(3) & p(2) \\ p(3) & 0 & -p(1) \\ -p(2)
   & p(1) & 0\end{pmatrix}$ - skew-symmetry matrix for vector $p$
5. $E=\begin{pmatrix} p+p & p-\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{array} \right] & p \times \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{array} \right] \end{pmatrix}$ - matrix
6. $I_p=[p]_×[p]_×^T+EE^T$

---

**Task:**

Find general formula in vector-matrix form for derivative of matrix $I_p$ by vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, i.e. $\frac{dI_p}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$

---

**My considerations:**

If we pay attention, then everything is based on the matrix $\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$. But I need to find a formula that does not require a manual transition to skew-symmetric matrices, i.e. everything happens automatically, and in return we get full matrix $\frac{dI_p}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$.

**EDIT:**

For one coordinate it will look like this to get the derivative of the skew-symmetric matrix.

$\frac{d[p]_x}{d\phi}=\frac{dp}{d\phi}\times\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right]$

$\frac{d[p]_x}{d\xi}=\frac{dp}{d\xi}\times\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{array} \right]$

$\frac{d[p]_x}{d\psi}=\frac{dp}{d\phi}\times\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right]$

How to "pack" it in one operation?

**EDIT №2:**

$\frac{d[p]_x}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}=[Skew^T(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right])\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right] \otimes I_n);Skew^T(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{array} \right])\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right] \otimes I_n);Skew^T(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right])\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right] \otimes I_n)$

Comment: Isn't $E = \left[ 2p, 0, 0\right]$?

Comment: see edit, there was mistake

Comment: $I_p$ is 3x3 matrix, so your final object will have 27 elements. The final formula may depend on exact alignment of the elements in 2D matrix you are after (if you want to keep them like this). I suggest you start with working out derivatives for components separately, and then find a nice way to pack them.

Comment: One can prove that $[p]_\times [p]_\times^\top = p^\top p I_3 - p p^\top$.
Then, it follows from the chain rule.

Comment: @Tomek, see my edit please

Comment: @SimonEatwell how to convert $\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ and original vector $[0,0,1]$ to $\frac{dp}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$. What formula i may use ?

Comment: @dtn could I write some partial results as an answer?

Comment: @SimonEatwell yes, and than i test them in Mathematica

Comment: @SimonEatwell see my edit №2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your second edit.
Replying to your first edit, it also takes the form:
$$
  \operatorname{vec}\frac{d [p]_\times}{d \theta}
=
\left(
  \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}_\times
\oplus
  \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}_\times
\oplus
  \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}_\times
\right)
  \operatorname{vec}\frac{d p}{d \theta}
$$
Here, $\operatorname{vec}\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^3$, and $A \oplus B = \begin{bmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix}$ for matrices $A, B$.
However, I argue that $\frac{d [p]_\times}{d \theta}$ has 27 entries to be determined as @tomek pointed out.
Since $[p]_\times \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, $\frac{d [p]_\times}{d \theta}$ is the derivative of the map $\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}, \theta \mapsto [p]_\times$ evaluated at $\theta$, i.e., $\left[\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto L(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3})\right]_\theta \in L(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3\times 3} \cong \mathbb{R}^{27}$.

If $\frac{d I_p}{d p}$ is attained, the chain rule can take over the analysis.
Let $I_p = A(p) + B(p)$ with $A(p) = [p]_\times [p]_\times^\top$ and $B(p) = EE^\top$.
Since $A(p) = p^\top p I_3 - pp^\top$, the derivative $\frac{d A}{dp} = A'(p)$ where $A' : \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto L(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3})$ satisfies $A'(p)(x) = 2p^\top x I_3 - (xp^\top + px^\top)$, as $$\begin{align*}
  A(p + h) - A(p)
&=
  p^\top h I_3
+
  h^\top p I_3
+
  h^\top h I_3
-
  hp^\top
-
  ph^\top
-
  hh^\top
\\&=
  2p^\top h I_3 - (hp^\top + ph^\top) + o(h)
.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i work on it in Mathematica. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201386/formula-for-the-transition-from-tensors-to-vectors-in-matrix-calculus Please see also answer and my edit at this topic

Comment: I see.
Good for you.
Unless you directly work with high order tensors, gluing or reshaping would most likely be required.
I was about to proceed to applying the chain rule.
Should I continue?
My approach is to differentiate by the definition of maps between two normed spaces, and flatten them to matrices in the end.

Comment: Yes, let's continue working on this. Despite some advances in this area, it will be important to evaluate alternatives.